# Lack of virtual destructor when doing "delete this"

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-destructor, self-destruction

Section [16.15 of the C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.15) discusses `delete this` and then mentions:

> Naturally the usual caveats apply in cases where your this pointer is
>   a pointer to a base class when you don't have a virtual destructor.

Why is this true? Consider this code:

```
class ISuicidal {
public:
    virtual void suicide() = 0;
};

class MyKlass : public ISuicidal {
public:
    MyKlass() {
        cerr << "MyKlass constructor\n";
    }

    ~MyKlass() {
        cerr << "MyKlass destructor\n";
    }

    void suicide() {
        delete this;
    }
};
```

Used thus:

```
int main()
{
    ISuicidal* p = new MyKlass;
    p->suicide();
    return 0;
}
```

In the call `p->suicide()`, the destructor of `MyKlass` is called as expected, *even though `ISuicidal` has no virtual destructor*.

To me this makes sense, because in `MyKlass::suicide`, the static type of `this` is known to be `MyKlass*`, so the correct destructor is invoked. This is easy to verify by placing `typeid` calls inside `suicide`.

So is the FAQ entry inaccurate, or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding.  Implement the suicide function (ie delete this) in ISuicidal and you will find that when the this pointer is a base class calling delete on it doesn't call the derived class's destructor.

Answer (score 4):

In your function `suicide(),`
You are using `delete this;`
Here, the `this` pointer corresponds to the class MyKlass, as the function is defined in MyKlass and not ISuicidal, and therefore the destructor of MyKlass is called.

If you had defined the function in ISuicidal, then it would not call the destructor of MyKlass unless you declare a virtual destructor in ISuicidal.

Answer (score 2):

the problem arises if you introduce another real class in the hierarchy that derives from MyClass (e.g. MyClass2).

```
class ISuicidal {
public:
    virtual void suicide() = 0;
};

class MyKlass : public ISuicidal {
public:
    MyKlass() {
       cerr << "MyKlass constructor\n";
    }

    ~MyKlass() {
        cerr << "MyKlass destructor\n";
    }

    void suicide() {
        delete this;
    }
};

class MyKlass2 : public MyKlass {
public:
    MyKlass2() {
        cerr << "MyKlass2 ctr"<<std::endl;
    } 

    ~MyKlass2() {
        cerr << "MyKlass2 dtr"<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyKlass* p = new MyKlass2;
    delete p; //destructor of base class called, not the destructor of MyKlass2 because
              //the destructor is not virtual
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`class Child : public MyKlass {
  ~Child () {}
};`

`ISuicidal* p = new Child;`

`p->suicide();  // ~Child() not called !`

Comment: Now only that: the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

it's safe as long as you call the exact destructor of the instance (e.g. do not call the destructor of a base).

therefore, you can safely accomplish this by properly implementing `suicide()` for every subclass - or by creating an external deleter function which is accessible to `this` (or whatever manages the lifetime of `this`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding it.  The issue occurs when you call delete this in the base class, that is when the this pointer has a type of pointer to the base class.

> Naturally the usual caveats apply in cases where your this pointer is
>   a pointer to a base class when you don't have a virtual destructor.

In your example this is not a pointer to the base class but rather a pointer to the derived class.